# Cast R objects into Python ones with rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

The question:  how to cast R objects to python ones

My case: I need to use the result of cor.test() into a python routine.

```
correlation = robjects.r('function(x, y) cor.test(x, y)')
corr= correlation(robjects.IntVector(goodtotemp), robjects.IntVector(goodGDPs))
print corr

print corr[3]
print 'coef:',type(corr[3])
```

outputs, as expected:

```
     cor 
0.984881 
coef: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector'>
```

Howover, I can't use corr[3] as an python object,

```
c=corr[3]
print 'c:',c*10., type(c)
```

look (Here's how I know that I'm doing something wrong!), the output:

```
c:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GDPAnalyzer.py", line 234, in <module>
    print 'c:',c*10., type(c)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'FloatVector' and 'float'
```

Any hint/help is appreciated!

Comment: As described in the error message, you cannot multiply a `FloatVector` and a `float`. Try to explicitly cast `c` to a `float` - like this - `float(c)*10` and see if it works.

Comment: that's not really it. Doing :=>  float(c)*10 gives:=> c:getsegcount
Segmentation fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmentation fault is a something that should be reported as an rpy2 bug. Otherwise, try either:

```
c.ro * 3
```

or:

```
c[0] * 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Python really does not support the concept of `casting`. It's true that in some limited circumstances it does do something like casting with built-in types.

But beyond that it is up to the programmer to CONVERT objects from one form to another or to create some form of facade or shim object that makes the R object behave like a Python one.

Try `print type(corr[3])` to see what Python type is being used. It might just be a string representation of the number, in which case you could use `eval()` to convert it to a float.